# AddContentTypeField - cannot add field to Content Type

Tags: content-type, elements-xml

I have a list with content type in it. I'm trying to add a field to this content type so I can use it in the library.
Here's I've added Elements.1.0.0.1.xml file to Content Type:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
     <Field ID="{63F353F8-F206-4BB0-A3C1-1B8FA9E43C63}" DisplayName="Dull field" Name="DULLfield" Type="Text" Group="RM" Overwrite="TRUE" />
    </Elements>
```

Then I've added Upgrade Action to Feature.Template.xml:

```
    <UpgradeActions>
    <VersionRange BeginVersion="0.0.0.0" EndVersion="10.0.0.0">
      <ApplyElementManifests>
        <ElementManifest Location="MyContentType\Elements.1.0.0.1.xml"/>
      </ApplyElementManifests>
      <AddContentTypeField ContentTypeId="0x0120D520005C2CAF72F4414435A29E0ACDC59F28D9" FieldId="{63F353F8-F206-4BB0-A3C1-1B8FA9E43C63}" PushDown="TRUE"/>
    </VersionRange>
  </UpgradeActions>
```

Then I run following script with no errors or warnings:

```
    Update-SPSolution -Identity sharepointproject1.wsp -LiteralPath  "C:\SharePointProject1.wsp" -GA
CDeployment
```

Now I can see new field in Site Columns, but not in my Content Type. I suppose  `PushDown="TRUE"` parameter has to add new field to a content type, but it doesn't. What do I miss?

======== Update ========
Deployed solution with Version = 1.0.0.0, then changed Version to 2.0.0.0, Publish WSP file to local disk, run Update-SPSolution. When I get Solution version via PowerShell

```
$f = Get-SPFeature | where{$_.DisplayName -eq '
myfeature'}
$f.version
```

It's still 1.0.0.0.
I've opened wsp feature.xml file inside wsp file - it has correct version 2.0.0.0

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally got the upgrade done. Here's a list of actions I proceeded:

1.Update spsolution (.wsp file):

```
   Update-SPSolution -Identity SharePointProject58.wsp -LiteralPath "<Path>" -GACDeployment
```

2.Upgrade feature:

```
    $feature = $web.Features | where{$_.Definition.DisplayName -eq '*myfeature*'} 
$feature.Upgrade($true)
```

And the most important part: You have to restart console after every time you update solution, otherwise it sticks to old version!
Here's good [article](http://sisharepoint.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/using-the-featureupgrading-event-to-upgrade-features-sharepoint-2010/) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Give versioning to the feature, i.e. VersionRange id, then remove from VersionRange the BeginVersion property.

Exemple:

```
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Version="10.0.0.0">
  <UpgradeActions>
    <VersionRange EndVersion ="10.0.0.0">
      <ApplyElementManifests>
        <ElementManifest Location="MyContentType\Elements.1.0.0.1.xml"/>
      </ApplyElementManifests>
      <AddContentTypeField ContentTypeId="0x0120D520005C2CAF72F4414435A29E0ACDC59F28D9" FieldId="{63F353F8-F206-4BB0-A3C1-1B8FA9E43C63}" PushDown="TRUE"/>
    </VersionRange>
  </UpgradeActions>
</Feature>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: didn't help ...

Comment: Where are your Elements definition?

Comment: Both old and new files are in the Content Type thread in solution explorer (Elements.xml and Elements.1.0.0.1.xml).
I've just now run powershell cmdlet to get the feature version and it's "0.0.0.0". Now I'm trying to figure out another way to set feature version...

Comment: It might seem stupid but is your SharePointProjectItem.spdata under the thread updated? Can you see the file in the feature? If yes then there might be a problem with the powershell script.

Comment: It's unupdated indeed! I've tried again just now:
Recreate Site Collection, then deploy feature with Version=1.0.0.0,
then changed Version to Version=2.0.0.0 in Feature.Template.xml, but after upgared feature still has Version=2.0.0.0 (checked bu powershell).
I think there's another way to set feature version...

Comment: Little update:
Changed feature's version number in feature's properties window, then ran Update-SPSolution, then I stuck... In all articles for feature update using Upgrade() command, but this command is not available in my case. I can only run Update(). But it doesn't change feature version.
Any ideas?